# How are RPM'S AND MPH recorded by Nissan Rogue?

Tags: nissan, speedometer, rogue

How are RPM'S and MPH recorded by Nissan and others.  Do they use the
cam as a pickup for RPM's and what is the pickup for mph (distributor, fly-wheel, what?).  Does changing rim size (17 vs 20") affect the speedometer or with modern computer technology is the system able to automatically adjust to the change and give the correct reading even with the rather dramatic change in rim & tire size.

Comment: Welcome to Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

Usually in newer vehicles (probably since about the early to mid 90's or a bit earlier), most vehicles use an electronic pickup somewhere in the final drive of the transmission to give a speed reading. Something like a [Hall Effect sensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall_effect_sensor) is used (usually) to give the computer a count, which is read over time and thus the computer can tell how fast the vehicle is going, which it then commands the speedometer to display so you can read it. It only know this count and then does its thing. If you change the rolling diameter of the tire, the computer doesn't know the difference, and thus your display is going to be screwed up. To fix the issue, you have to go into the computer and "tune" it to understand what the new "count" should be over time so it can then display it correctly. This can be done through a tuner shop or there are some handhelds on the market which can do it as well.

The RPMs are not used in any of these calculations. RPMs denote the engine speed and not the vehicle speed. Since most vehicles have gears in the transmission, any time the tranny changes up to the next gear, the speed of the engine goes down, but the vehicle speed usually goes up or stays the same. Due to this, it wouldn't make sense to try and utilize the engine speed to calculate. This also alleviates any issues with slippage in the transmission (especially an automatic) and gives a more accurate reading.

Comment: A bit more on fixing the issue of the incorrect speed with larger/smaller wheels. You can get 'speedo healers' which you wire in a program to fix the speed(calibrating it with a gps speedo). I believe they work by altering the signal between the ecu and pickup.

Comment: SPEED is usually determined using ABS's wheels sensor. Different RIM size is not necessarily correlated with different wheel circumference. Foe an extreme example, MINI offers rims from 15 to 18 inch but the external tyre size is the same. Google the meaning on the marking on the tyres to understand :)

Comment: @Caterpillaraoz - Which cars are you talking about when you say "*speed is usually determined using ABS's wheels sensor*"? The only cars which I've dealt with which do are ones which have been modified by the owner to use the sensor at the wheel. References would be great!

Comment: The very most of the car from 2000 onwards. The most recent also use GPS as calibration

Comment: @Caterpillaraoz - And I should believe you because you say this on the internet?

Comment: You do not need to believe me, logic is enough :) Basically all modern car have (at least) ABS.
ABS is required to know individual wheels` speeds, hence the speed sensors on the wheels. 
Speedometer needs a  less precise and fast data reading, so natural and logical choice is to "share" the speed reading from the ABS/Traction control unit. 
The vehicle speed extimation done by abs is quite complex, enabling you to have coherent reading even in case of wheel splippage, something the old sensor-on-final drive system cannot.

Comment: http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6621232/?reload=true Here and in many articles the evolution in speed sensing can be seen, from final-drive-reading- to sharing-with-abs-sensors in the beginning to even more fine tuned systems, needed when stability control is included, that include gps calibration and multi-component speed measurements done with an IMU.

Comment: "In many articles" is a stretch, in fact this article is a stretch, as the first statement in the abstract, is an abstract itself. It's a supposition on the part of the writers about what they are trying to say and is no real "proof" in and of itself. I will give you the wheel speed sensors *can* be used for speed sensing, but nothing you've shown me proves it is used in almost every vehicle since 2000. Your statements by far over estimates your assumptions.

Comment: And really, any of your comments do not discount what I'm trying to say to the OP, nor the validity of my answer above. None of the engine sensors are used to estimate the vehicle speed.

Comment: @Caterpillaraoz - Also, I've confirmed the Nissan Rogue uses a transmission mounted speed sensor up through 2017. If you look up the parts listed for it on [rockauto.com](http://www.rockauto.com/en/catalog/nissan,2017,rogue,2.0l+l4+electric/gas,3440136,electrical), you'll find it. You'll also see the Altima, Juke, Maxima, Murano, NV200, Pathfinder, Quest, Sentra, Versa, and X-Trail use the same part (not all through 2017, but all in the 201x years).

Comment: I do not need how to have how a car sensor system works explained to me, having been that my previous job. I was just "keeping it simple". To add clarity: sensors on crankshaft and on camshaft are used (mainly) to determine engine rpm (there are two or more because of timing control / vvt systems), sensors on wheels and (sometimes) final drive sensor, GPS, IMU are used by an estimator to determine (3D, internally expressed as quaternions) vehicle speed.

Comment: @Caterpillaraoz - Obviously final drive sensors are still used a lot more than you believe them to be.